# How do I free port 80?

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

the color of my wamp server is orange.I checked it and i found my Apache didn't run cause of port 80 is busy,I found that microsoft_httpAPI/2.0 is using this port,but I don't know how can i free this port.

Comment: This is a well known conflict with Skype, which you probably have installed. Either you remove skype (its sole purpose is to sniff at you anyway...) or you change the port of your http server, for example to 8080.

Comment: I saw this question before asking my question,and I tried all ways that they answered in that question,but none of them solved my problem.I removed Skype,I changed the port address to 8080 ... but the icon is orange yet... .

Comment: Then obviously the issue is not that port 80 is already bound, is it?

Comment: yes it is!when i try to check port 80 the message shown  is"your port 80 is already used by : server :microsoft_HTTPAPI/2.0".

Comment: Yes, but if you configured your http server to use another port then this should be irrelevant. Once some service is installed on MS-Windows systems it is hard to find out _why_ that is the case, what caused that. Just like with installed software on those systems: impossible to know why it was installed, triggered by what and if it can be removed. One of the many short comings in that platform.

Comment: I myself found the way to solve my problem!the problem was related to SQL Server Reporting.I stopped it and my wamp server icon turned to green!

Comment: tanx anyway arkascha.cause you spent time to answer me... .